# how to configure tplink wireless router for best connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

i have a TPlink wireless router (WR940N) with 5mbps fiber connection. i have 17 desktop computers connected by cable with static ip starting from 192.168.0.11 to 192.168.0.28 and i set the DHCP starting ip from 192.168.0.100 to 192.168.0.199 for devices on the wifi. most of the time the connection goes too low even it cant open a single web page. this mostly happen when devices are connected to the wifi network. i thought someone might be downloading large files, but when i check the wireless statistics, no one is using more than a few kbps.

is it because of the IP addresses?

Comment: [How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html)

Comment: You may want to change the wifi channel on your router... you may have interference from other surrounding networks. Also, although it's not a massive problem and it's totally up to you, but why have static IPs for your PCs and DHCP for your wifi? Is there specific reason for this separation?

Comment: i assigned static IPs for my PCs and DHCP for my wifi because i want to control the bandwidth of each PCs on peak hours.